Can Buckmaster-Vicol paradoxical solutions to Navier Stokes show macroscopic motion?
Villani, in his paper "Paradoxe de Scheffer-Shnirelman ..." (MR2648676, Zbl 1404.35338),  describes the paradoxical solutions to the Euler equation by Scheffer and Shnirelman, in the form given by De Lellis and Székelyhidi using convex integration.  In short, these people give weak solutions to the (incompressible) Euler equation, with no force term, where a fluid initially stationary begins moving with high velocity and then stops again, apparently in wild contradiction to conservation of energy.  Then, Buckmaster and Vicol in their paper "On The Non-Uniqueness Of Weak Solutions Of The Navier Stokes Equations" (MR3898708, Zbl 1412.35215) gave solutions like that for Navier-Stokes (with non-zero viscosity).
Villani points out that the flow in De Lellis and Székelyhidi solutions to the Euler equation can be given arbitrarily high velocity  but in the example he gives, the flow "oscillates extremely rapidly, so that one will observe almost no movement on a macroscopic scale" and so rapidly that "perhaps one cannot convert their motion into mechanical energy."
By rapid oscillation Villani does not just mean the solutions have high frequency components but that they are concentrated in high frequencies and he quantifies this by saying they have low $H^{-1}$ norm, where $H^{-1}$  is the distributional dual to the Sobolev space $H^1 = W^{1,2}$.   This works because of way the $H^{-1}$ norm of a tempered distribution $f$ grows or diminishes with the Fourier transform $\hat{f}$.
$$\| f\| _{H^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^n)}\ =\ \sqrt{\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}   \int (1+ \vert\xi \rvert^2)^{-1} \vert \hat{f}(\xi)\rvert^2\, d\xi }$$
My question is, can De Lellis and Székelyhidido solutions or Buckmaster and Vicol solutions also show macroscopic motion?  Villani does not define the term "macroscopic."  But I think we could take it to mean flow with support the open unit ball $B_1(0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ over a time interval $0<t<T$ where $T-t>1$, and with high enough speed and slow enough oscillation that for some time interval of length 1 the flow in some smaller open ball $B_r(p)\subset B_1(0)$ with radius $r>1/1000$ maintains motion in (nearly) one direction long enough to cover a coordinate distance of at least $r/2$.
Comment on "macroscopic."   Villani highlights how his example of a paradoxical solution is practically invisible and undetectable: "one will observe almost no movement on a macroscopic scale ... perhaps one cannot convert the motion into mechanical energy."  He does not say all Scheffer-Shnirelman and De Lellis-Székelyhidi solutions are this way.  So far I cannot tell whether all of them are, and that is my question here.  There is no intrinsic sense of "macroscopic."  The spatial  coordinates for the Euler and Navier-Stokes equations could stand for microns, or meters, or parsecs.  So the sense of "macroscopic" can only be relative.  What makes sense to me, for the paradoxical solutions, is to regard the compact support for a given solution as the basic case of macroscopic, and say spatial features of the solution are macroscopic if their (linear) size is at least within a factor of $10^{- 3}$ of that compact support.  I do not offer this as precisely right, only as precisely specifiable.  Better suggestions are welcome. Anyway, this standard means you cannot trivially turn every paradoxical solution into a macroscopic one by the natural scaling on Navier-Stokes.  Re-scaling the solution will also re-scale the support and thus change what counts as macroscopic.

Given that you can just add together solutions supported in disjoint regions to form new solutions it seems to me that the answer to the question is trivially negative unless it is formulated somewhat differently.

@MartinHairer Okay now I see what you mean about the title question.   I have reformulated the precise question.  The original title question did not say what counts as "high" oscillation, but in those terms what I mean is oscillation concentrated in high frequencies, or (what I believe is the same) $H^{-1}$ norm negligible compared to $H^1$ norm. But I reformulated it all more explicitly in terms of "macroscopic" motion.

The short answer is no, at least for the Euler equation solutions described by  De Lellis and Székelyhidi.  The solution Villani says has "almost no motion on a macroscopic scale" is typical of those.  But this may have more to do with research goals than with limitations of the tools.  Macroscopic motion is physically interesting, but not very interesting in this context, because no one believes these solutions are physically real anyway.
De Lellis and Székelyhidi do not present lots and lots of very different solutions.  They present solutions that reveal what can be expected about the existence and uniqueness of weak solutions.  They use their technique to show, for example, that even the strongest of five different plausible versions of energy conservation (or, non-increase) fails to guarantee uniqueness of Euler solutions at low levels of regularity.  For this it suffices to look at solutions supported on a ball with unit volume, which alter the "subsolution" (also called "presolution") 0 through an infinite succession of forces with arbitrarily small $H^{-1}$ norm. As Villani remarks, this allows building up the speed of flow, while producing ever more rapid oscillation so the flow never persists through any appreciable distance. I have not yet worked through the Buckmaster and Vicol proof, for Navier-Stoke.  But so far as I have found in the literature, macroscopically paradoxical solutions have not been pursued.
